# Unexpected result using linalg.matrix_rank in numpy.linalg (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, rank, determinants

I am trying to calculate the rank of a large (182 x 182) matrix. As a test, I put

```
from numpy import linalg as LA

# Some other code ...

# R is a 182 x 182 matrix
det = LA.det(R)
print('|R|:')
print(det)            # Prints out 1.528938248893958e-29

tol = 10*det

rank = LA.matrix_rank(R, 10*det)

print('Rank of R:')
print(rank)           # Prints out 182!
```

So this calculates the determinant of R, multiplies this by 10 (so it is obviously greater than the determinant) and passes this value as the tolerance to matrix_rank. However, this prints out 182 (the size of the matrix), which I do not understand. I am expecting matrix_rank to give the number of singularities greater than the tolerance. Since the determinate of the entire matrix (which is a singularity of the matrix) is smaller than this, I would expect to get less than 182.

Could anyone shed any light on this for me? Am I doing something wrong / misunderstood something or is this some kind of bug?

Comment: To make this an MCVE, add the initialization of `R`, say as a random matrix

Comment: Also, 1e-28 is a really tiny number. You're comparing roundoff error of zero: it's simply unreliable

Comment: Find the singular values using `eig` or so. You'll see what I mean

Comment: The code is simple, `S=svd(arr)` and count values relative the `tol`.

Comment: I think I see my conceptual error now. I had not realised that the 'singular values' are the square roots of the eigenvalues of R times it transpose. Rather, I thought that they referred to the largest determinants formed by striking out rows and columns from the matrix. This was based on the definition of rank as being the number of rows of the largest determinant so formed from the matrix. So I was thinking of 'singular' referring to a determinant that is nearly zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix rank uses singular value decomposition, if you want to make sure your matrix will be considered with incomplete rank your tolerance should be calculated like this

```py
_, s, _ = LA.svd(R)
tol = np.min(abs(s)) * 10;
```